# simpleError in get_soils_raster(...): http error 400

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm trying to get multiple attributes for multiple locations with a nested loop. Code worked fine on the weekend but today I'm getting errors.

I've tried clearing my DNS cache, clearing/restarting R session and updating package. Tried to troubleshoot the function but can't find get_soils_raster function.

MRE: this is part of the loop I use to collect the data.

```
LATITUDE = -28.77837
LONGITUDE = 114.6572
soil_attributes_available <- slga_attribute_info %>% 
                             filter(WA == TRUE) %>% 
                             select(Code) %>% 
                             unlist() %>% 
                             unname()


soil_composition_matrix <- lapply(soil_attributes_available, list)
SOIL_DEPTH <- 1 # 0-5cm
BUFFER_AROUND_POINT <- 3 # ~270m radius

 for (code in 1:length(soil_attributes_available)) {
     result <- tryCatch(
         {unname(
             unlist(
                 get_soils_point(product = 'WA', 
                                 attribute = soil_attributes_available[code],
                                 component = 'VAL',
                                 depth = SOIL_DEPTH,
                                 poi = c(LONGITUDE, LATITUDE),
                                 buff = BUFFER_AROUND_POINT,
                                 buff_shp = 'circle',
                                 stat = 'mean')[1]
             )
         )
         }, 
         error = function(e){print(e)}
     )
     print(result)
 }
```

When I ran it on the weekend I would get datapoints for every iteration but now I'm getting errors randomly:

```
<simpleError in get_soils_raster(product, attribute, component, depth, aoi, skip_val = TRUE): http error 400.>
```

Any suggestions, @obrl-soils ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_soils_raster` is an internal-only function - you can view it by using `:::` instead of `::`, or visit the github repo.

The issue you're having appears to be with the underlying service itself though, not the wrapper code - you can tell because the same request sometimes works and sometimes does not, so the issue is not a malformed request as the error code might suggest. I can replicate the inconsistent behaviour and I'll follow up with the service provider. I note that there've been some major internet outages in Aus within the last 24 hours, so this may resolve itself.

In the meantime, you may wish to try an alternative API endpoint available at http://www.asris.csiro.au/ASRISApi#!/SLGA32Services/SLGA_DrillSLGA. I haven't built it into `slga` yet - I'm still using the WCS services for my point queries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll retry it tomorrow.
The triple colon is a new tip for me as well! Thanks!